# JS/jQuery - How can I a number from an element ID and use it as a variable in functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, element

Basically, I want one function to act on multiple elements individually depending on which one is clicked.

I have 3 of these functions that do the same thing:

```
$("#morelink1, #pic1").click(function() {
var imgHeight = $(".pic").height();
var image = $('#more1').parent('.content').siblings(
  '.image');
if ($('#more1').is(":visible")) {
  $("#more1").slideUp(200, "linear");
  image.height(contHeight);
  showtext1();
  $("#closemore1").hide();
} else {
  $("#more1").slideDown(200, "linear");
  image.height(imgHeight);
  hidebutton1();
  hidetext1();
}
 });
```

As you can see, the names of the IDs I am working with in this function all end in "1."  I duplicated this function for 2 and 3.

Instead of duplicating, there must be a way to extract the number from `#morelink1`, make it a variable, and append the number to the ID in the function.

I'd like to have something like:

```
var NUMBER = [get the number from the ID of the element that was clicked];

$("#morelink + NUMBER, #pic + NUMBER").click(function() {
```

I also have functions built into this function - `showtext1()`, `hidebutton1()`, and `hidetext1()`. Those are also duplicated with just the number changed. I'd like to be able to do the same thing with those within this function.  Would it be something like `showtext(NUMBER)`?

I have looked around and can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

Are there other ways to do this, like passing a number to the function?

Answer (score 2):

Instead, just modify your selector to use [the "starts with" operator](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) instead of specifying the `id` completely:

```
$("[id^='morelink'], [id^='pic']").click(function() {
```

That would match every element where the `id` value starts with `'morelink'` or `'pic'`, regardless of what the rest of the `id` is.

If you still need that value inside the click handler, you can parse it from the `id` of the current element.

```
var idString = $(this).attr('id');
// use whatever logic you define to parse the number value.
// for example, maybe a regular expression which matches only numeric characters?
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks like what I need. I do need the value, because these are like "read more" links, so I don't want all of the items to expand.

I also just came across a codepen of something similar to what I want to do that uses `$('.more').each(function()`.  Would using classes be a better approach?

Comment: @AdamDallas: If the target of any given operation in the click handler can be identified in the DOM relative to the clicked element, you might not need to parse the value at all.  Often something like `$(this).closest('some common parent element').find('target element')` will do the trick.  It's up to you which would be easier to maintain.

Comment: @AdamDallas: A better approach for what exactly?  You generally don't want to *create* a click handler in a loop.  You could use classes to identify your elements, that's fine.  But don't think of this in terms of using loops.  Just use a selector to identify you're clickable elements and then a single click handler to respond to that event.

Answer (score 0):

If you could share your whole code, it would help. From my understanding, it should be something along these lines:

```
// Append click event to elements whose id starts with morelink or pic.
$('[id^="morelink"], id^=["pic"]').click(function() {
  // Get id of current clicked element.
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  // Use RegExp to extract number.
  var number = id.match(/[\d]+/)[0];

  // Your functions starting.
  var imgHeight = $(".pic").height(); //should this be pic + NUMBER?
  var image = $('#more' + number).parent('.content').siblings('.image');

  if ($('#more' + number).is(":visible")) {
    $('#more' + number).slideUp(200, "linear");
    image.height(contHeight);
    // Executes selectMore1(); if number = 1
    window['showtext' + number]();
   $("#closemore" + number).hide();
  } else {
    $("#more" + number).slideDown(200, "linear");
    image.height(imgHeight);
    // Executes hidebutton1(); if number = 1
    window['hidebutton' + number]();
    // Executes hidetext1(); if number = 1
    window['hidetext' + number]();
  }
});
```

However, I don't think hidebutton1() should exist, but hidebutton(number). That's why I asked for the whole code to really understand what you meant by creating multiple functions at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the prefix for variable names, suffix with the number(s) you want. Then plug into the jQuery selector. I've done that before, if direct plug in like `$(YourNewVariableForID)` won't work, then try `$("#" + eval(YourNewVariableForID))`.